# django - Remove users from django database if user is removed from database from LDAP server

Tags: django, ldap, django-auth-ldap

I'm currently using `django-auth-ldap` to authenticate with `LDAP`, and I've looked through all the docs for the library, it doesn't mention what happens to the django database when the database we are authenticating against removes the user.

I know we can do a check when we authenticate to make sure if the user is removed, but how do I clean up the user since a user will be created if it's successfully authenticated. Do I just do it like I'd normally do with `Django` user object?

Thank you!